# Где взять полную базу городов SQL по странам?

Tags: sql, mysql

Что б допустим выбрал страну и можно было выбрать города области поселки и т.д.

Comment: Рекомендации сторонних ресурсов - не по теме StackOverflow на русском.

Answer (score 12):

[Бесплатная база стран и городов](http://citieslist.ru/)

Answer (score 3):

Вообще,если по России только, то есть [КЛАДР](http://www.gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/) - по идее должен всегда находиться в актуальном состоянии

Comment: КЛАДР заменён на [ФИАС][1], если что.

Обновления еженедельные, но сама база довольно-таки грязная.

В формате SQL ФИАС есть [тут][2].

  [1]:http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/NewsPage.aspx
  [2]:http://basicdata.ru/download/fias/